# Filter artifacts that get published to Artifactory

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to filter the artifacts that get published to Artifactory and running into two issues:

1) The include/exclude filtering is not working for me as expected.
2) I have not found a way to set it to exclude unpublished artifacts from buildinfo.

---

1) The relevant section of my jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
    def now = new Date()
    def changelist  = now.format("yyyyMMddHHmm", TimeZone.getTimeZone('US/Central'))

    def server = Artifactory.server env.ARTIFACTORY_SERVER_ID
    server.credentialsId = 'creds-artifactory'

    def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
    rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'releases-repo', snapshotRepo: 'snapshots-repo'
    rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'candidates-repo', snapshotRepo: 'snapshots-repo'

    rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("myGroupId:myDistArtifactId*")

    buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: "clean install -B -Dchangelist=.${changelist}".toString()

    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

I have tried also to exclude with no lock.  The only way I got this to work was to do a simple filter like exclude "*.zip".  But have not found any other way to make it work based on artifactId.  What am I missing?  Based on the [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) I saw this should be working.

2) The other issue is that the excluded artifacts (metadata) still get published since they are in my buildInfo but in Artifactory they show as being deleted (i.e. not attached binary).  is there a way to update buildInfo and remove the excluded artifacts?

Comment: When you run mvn clean install. an artifact is created and if your setting.xml point to your Artifactory, this artifact will be uploaded.  Why do you need filter or exclude certain files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins) documentation article will be helpful, see  uploading example:

```
def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
      {
        "pattern": "bazinga/*froggy*.zip",
        "target": "bazinga-repo/froggy-files/"
      }
    ]
}"""
server.upload spec: uploadSpec
```